# How To Deserialize JSON in vb,net with Multiple objects

Tags: json, vb.net

Below is a json file that needs to be deserialized and to be stored in different variables.

With this current json, which is returned by an API, I am unable to deserialize because it gives me and error -

Please help me on deserializing this particular json

I have added the code i used, but it returns wrong values and null reference.

```
{
  "result": {
    "candidates": [
      {
        "similarity": 0.1330482513,
        "person_id": "75741ea3-4d9b-4e25-8460-16444ee39946",
        "descriptor_id": "2f228007-350e-4d58-9897-4b62e9978081",
        "user_data": "Без названия (9)",
        "external_id": null
      }
    ],
    "face": {
      "id": "a1b224a3-60c6-4733-9bbc-136d53ea011c",
      "score": 0.9320185781
    }
  },
  "timestamp": 1569957900.1488559,
  "source": "search",
  "event_type": "match",
  "authorization": {
    "token_id": "71f9b3e0-51b1-480f-93b9-0e76e260bcbc",
    "token_data": "first token"
  },
  "template": {
    "descriptor_id": "a1b224a3-60c6-4733-9bbc-136d53ea011c"
  },
  "candidate": {
    "list_id": "6e64e600-cd77-4894-940e-6f7022d8aba8",
    "list_data": "FaceStream_search_list(DON'T DELETE)",
    "list_type": 1
  }
}
```

I have tried :

```
Public Class Rootobject
    Public Property result As Result
    Public Property timestamp As Single
    Public Property source As String
    Public Property event_type As String
    Public Property authorization As Authorization
    Public Property template As Template
    Public Property candidate As Candidate1
End Class

Public Class Result
    Public Property candidates() As Candidate
    Public Property face As Face
End Class

Public Class Face
    Public Property id As String
    Public Property score As Single
End Class
Public Class Candidate
    Public Property similarity As Double
    Public Property person_id As String
    Public Property descriptor_id As String
    Public Property user_data As String
    Public Property external_id As Object
End Class

Public Class Authorization
    Public Property token_id As String
    Public Property token_data As String
End Class
Public Class template
    Public Property descriptor_id As String
End Class
Public Class Candidate1
    Public Property list_id As String
    Public Property list_data As String
    Public Property list_type As Integer
End Class


''And used

 Dim Candidatess As New Candidate
        Candidatess = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Candidate)((JObject.Parse(e.Message)).ToString)
        msg(Candidatess.similarity.ToString)
        msg(Candidatess.descriptor_id.ToString)
        msg(Candidatess.person_id.ToString)

''REturns me Null
```

Comment: *"it gives me and error"*.  Keeping the error message secret is NEVER a good idea.

Comment: Why do you deserialize your JSON object to Candidate type instead of RootObject?

Comment: Similarity field  in that json - returns value .all other values its returning null values . eg : Similarity : i get value "0.1330482513" . but the remaining  "Person_id : "Noithing". Its not error , its not returning me anything.

Comment: Can you please post a sample code regards that . I am very new to vb.net .

Comment: In the `Result` class, change `Public Property candidates() As Candidate` to `Public Property candidates As List(Of Candidate)`. Then deserialize the JSON using the `RootObject` class (the type that represents the entry point of your JSON) (also, assuming `e.Message` contains the JSON string): `Dim candidates = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Rootobject)(e.Message)`

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Class Candidate
    Public Property similarity As Double
    Public Property person_id As String
    Public Property descriptor_id As String
    Public Property user_data As String
    Public Property external_id As Object
End Class

Public Class Face
    Public Property id As String
    Public Property score As Double
End Class
Public Class Result
    Public Property candidates As Candidate()
    Public Property face As Face
End Class
Public Class Authorization
    Public Property token_id As String
    Public Property token_data As String
End Class
Public Class Template
    Public Property descriptor_id As String
End Class

Public Class Candidate
    Public Property list_id As String
    Public Property list_data As String
    Public Property list_type As Integer
End Class

Public Class Candidates
    Public Property result As Result
    Public Property timestamp As Double
    Public Property source As String
    Public Property event_type As String
    Public Property authorization As Authorization
    Public Property template As Template
    Public Property candidate As Candidate
End Class

Public Function GetData(ApiEndpoint As Uri, ApiToken As String)
    Dim origResponse As HttpWebResponse = Nothing
    Dim objResponse As HttpWebResponse = Nothing
    Dim origReader As StreamReader = Nothing
    Dim objReader As StreamReader = Nothing

    Dim origRequest As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(HttpWebRequest.Create(ApiEndpoint), HttpWebRequest)
    origRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " & ApiToken)
    origRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = False
    origRequest.Method = "GET"

    'Call the API and get the JSON Response data
    origResponse = DirectCast(origRequest.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
    Dim Stream As Stream = origResponse.GetResponseStream()
    Dim sr As New StreamReader(Stream, Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8"))
    Dim myJsonResponse As String = sr.ReadToEnd()

    'Deserialize the Json 
    Dim objFormResults As Result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Result)(myJsonResponse)
```

'loop through the results
End Function